# Using jquery's .on and jQuery.noConflict but still can't get it working with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jquery to change the markup on a page that I have only partial control over.

Live page: http://demo.salsalabs.com/o/50531/p/dia/action3/common/public/?action_KEY=7679

The page loads jquery 1.3.2 (I have no control over this) and I'm also loading jquery 1.9.1 to work with Twitter's Bootstrap.

On the landing page you enter your zip code and click submit. Then using some ajax the page brings up your local representatives and another form. I'm using jquery to adjust the html markup on the page.

**The problem is that the markup changes are not applied to the ajaxed in content.**

Here is the JS that's not working as expected...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $bs("#postalCodeForm input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
      alert("Thanks for submitting a zip");
      $bs("#target-page .actioncontent").addClass("span6");
      $bs("#target-page .targets").addClass("span6");
   });
});
```

I think this all has to do with the fact that the initial "submit" button uses an onClick handler and I don't know how to work with that.

```
onclick="return submitPostalCode();return false;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If you can remove the original `onclick` handler, by all means do, even if programmatically

Comment: yeah. return false in the inline onclick function is your problem

Answer (score 1):

you could do this to get rid of it...

```
$('#postalCodeForm input[type=button]').attr('onclick', null);
```

if you need the previous function call, you could store it in a variable then execute it after you're code executes.